# Enforce unique constraint on a field

Tags: entities

For a content type (place), on creation, as the user is entering the name field, I would like to check the previous records for that field. If there is a match, I will present it to the user to prevent duplicate entries. is there way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Unique field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module.

> This module performs additional validation when a node is created or updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language, and CCK fields are unique within a given context.

Comment: I used the [unique field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) together with [Automatic nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) and [Autocomplete Widgets for Text and Number Fields](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_widgets) so the user is presented with the similar entries but not allowed to use one. Auto nodetitle is used to hide the title field but still use it for pathauto. Thank you Jimajamma.

Answer (score 1):

In D7 you could also implement your "place" as a taxonomy and then use a "auto tagging" widget. As users type in the place name they see similar names that are already entered. That would prevent miss spellings.

Comment: That would be very nice. Can you briefly describe how I can do that?

Comment: Ok so i setup a new dictionary named "place name". then I added a new "name" field to the "place" content type and made it an auto tagging widget for taxonomy. It works as you said, thank you.
Since I do not want the same data in two different fields, what I need is to get rid of the title field (which does not look possible) and convince pathauto to create urls from the new "place name" field (which also does not look possible). Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you use the "title" field as the "place name"?

Comment: I could not figure out a way to make the title field both unique and auto complete. I found a workaround though (in the comments of Jimajamma's answer).